# How to get bluetooth headphone audio controls to trigger button in iOS Swift iphone App

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am developing an audio player app in Swift and have completed the core functionality. I would like to set it up so that when you hit track next or track previous on bluetooth headphones it will trigger the previous and next buttons that are in the app already.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from Apple's documentation.

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [self playPauseToggle: nil]
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                [self nextTrack: nil]
                break;
...
```

And here's the function in swift:

```
func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(_ event: UIEvent)
```

I am not sure, however, if Apple will let you get away with handling these events in anyway other than their explicit expected behavior. If I click pause, for example, and it opens a URL or something like that, you can expect to be rejected or pulled from the store right away. If your previous and next buttons aren't directly related to audio playback this isn't allowed and will not fly.